# Gradle Tomcat Plugin Throwing Exception

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I'm getting the following exception during `tomcatRunWar`.

When I run the same from tomcat standalone and deploy the same war file it works fine.

```
Parse Fatal Error at line 96 column 11: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/scp-novatti-1.0/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 96; columnNumber: 11; Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1433)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1809)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/scp-novatti-1.0/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/scp-novatti-1.0/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 96; columnNumber: 11; Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
```

Comment: A sax parse exception likely means your web.xml find is malformed. Probably missing a tag or something. Please verify.

Comment: The same built war files get deployed to standalone tomcat and run fine, but not with the gradle tomcat plugin.

Comment: Possible to post your web.xml? At least, a section around line 96.